# nested timer code is not working

Tags: c#, timer, ienumerator

i made a traffic bot...it worked for one website. and i set it to multiple websites. 
therefore i coded like following.

```
 IEnumerator<string> proxies;
    IEnumerator<string> websites;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();

        string[] ipaddress = textBox2.Text.Split('\n');

        for(int i=0;i<Convert.ToInt32(ipaddress.Length);i++){

            strings.Add(ipaddress[i]);
        }


        proxies = strings.GetEnumerator();
        timer1.Start();

        //websites = strings.GetEnumerator();
        //timer1.Start();
      //  websites.MoveNext();
        proxies.MoveNext();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        WinInetInterop.SetConnectionProxy(proxies.Current);
        label1.Text = proxies.Current;
        string[] website = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
        List<string> stringsweb = new List<string>();

        for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(website.Length); j++)
        {

            stringsweb.Add(website[j]);
        }

        websites = stringsweb.GetEnumerator();
        timer2.Enabled = true;


            //webBrowser1.Navigate(website[0]);

        timer1.Enabled = proxies.MoveNext();



    }

   private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(websites.Current);
        label2.Text = websites.Current;
        timer2.Enabled = websites.MoveNext();
    }
```

As you can see i called a timer2_Tick method in timer1_Tick... But my code is not working...

Problem is it doesn't call timer2_Tick method in timer1_tick,So websites are not loading...

Timer1,Timer2 intervals =10s

I want to do

get one proxy from textbox2 ---> load 2 website for that proxy

Please show me my error

Comment: The Array's Length property is already an integer. No need to Convert it. And you can assign the list directly from Split using _string.Split('\n').ToList();_

Comment: ok.but it is working without any issues ,it is not the error.

Comment: I would set the Timer1 disabled when it ticks and keep it disabled untile the Timer2 ticks and complete the navigate to the site. At that point I would disable Timer2 and reenable Timer1

Comment: could you show me it as a answer. then i can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but I suppose that your timers overlaps each other so, you could try to better synchronize their ticks

```
IEnumerator<string> proxies;
IEnumerator<string> websites;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    strings = textBox2.Text.Split('\n').ToList();
    proxies = strings.GetEnumerator();
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the first timer until the second one completes
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    WinInetInterop.SetConnectionProxy(proxies.Current);
    label1.Text = proxies.Current;
    List<string> stringsweb = textBox1.Text.Split('\n').ToList();
    websites = stringsweb.GetEnumerator();
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(websites.Current);
    label2.Text = websites.Current;

    // Let's continue with the second timer until completition
    timer2.Enabled = websites.MoveNext();

    // Reenable the first when the second timer completes
    if(!timer2.Enabled) 
        timer1.Enabled = strings.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: your code is working. but there are some step which is worthless, I don't know where are those in code